# How do I make a thread dump with MONO?

Tags: .net, mono, stack-trace, thread-dump

How can I show the threads (stacktraces) in a hanging application that run with MONO?

I know that I can do it in .NET with the Managed Stack Explorer (MSE). Because the application hang only with MONO that I need to do it with MONO.

Or there are any other ideas how I can find the place of hanging?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming you're on Linux/Unix, not Windows, send a SIGQUIT signal to your program. This can be done with

```
kill -QUIT $PID
```

where $PID is the pid of your program. Mono will then dump stack traces of all threads to stdout. Note that although the process stays running after this, you should not expect it to remain usable/stable.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGQUIT for some background.

Note: The thread dump will *not* print out in the terminal window where you ran the `kill` command. It will appear in the stderr of the mono process.

Comment: how do I find the stderr of the mono process? And can I redirect it to a file?

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to quickly grab a managed stack trace using GDB. Execute `gdb`; use sudo if you're not root or debugging a process owned by your user.

Execute this script which I got from the [debugging Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/) page on mono-project.org:

```
handle SIGXCPU SIG33 SIG35 SIGPWR nostop noprint

define mono_stack
 set $mono_thread = mono_thread_current ()
 if ($mono_thread == 0x00)
   printf "No mono thread associated with this thread\n"
 else
   set $ucp = malloc (sizeof (ucontext_t))
   call (void) getcontext ($ucp)
   call (void) mono_print_thread_dump ($ucp)
   call (void) free ($ucp)
 end
end
```

If you like you can drop these commands in your `~/.gdbinit` so you don't have to copy and paste all the time.

Now attach to your PID:

```
attach 12345
```

Note that the whole process is now paused so if you're doing this in production it is advisable to script this so it's as fast as possible.

To get your stack trace, execute `mono_stack` as defined above. Note that you won't see the output in gdb but in stdout. If you run your process with upstart you can just edit the upstart job to use `console log` to log it to `/var/log/upstart`.

You may be interested in another thread than your main thread however. To do so, execute `info threads` to get your thread list and `thread 2` to switch to thread #2. For more information on thread debugging, see [debugging programs with multiple threads](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html) in the GDB docs.

Once you're done, execute `quit`, and your program will continue working.

Comment: The instructions are very helpful, but there seems to be an issue on x64 with this line: `if ($mono_thread == 0x00)`, it throws: `Invalid type combination in equality test`.

Comment: Sorry for the very slow response. I expect that to make it work on x64 you would need to patch this to `($mono_thread == 0x0000)` (experiment with different numbers of zeroes until it works). I now haven't used Mono in some time so I don't have an easy way to test I'm afraid.