# How to print thread stacks from inside mono

Tags: c#, mono, dllimport

I'm using Mono 3.2.7 on OSX. I would like my program to be able to trigger a thread dump for the diagnostic exports.

```
[DllImport("libmono", EntryPoint = "_mono_threads_request_thread_dump")]
public static extern void MonoThreadsRequestThreadDump();
```

Nothing is written to stdout when this is called.

Removing the leading underscore causes a native exception in Mono as expected.

What am I doing incorrectly or what is a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You could send your own process the `SIGQUIT` signal (as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2068471/21567)).

Comment: @Christian.K "you should not expect it to remain usable/stable" is a deal breaker.

Comment: Yes, it would. But without any offence to the person who answered the other question, I would not blindly take that for granted. Just handling SIGQUIT is not reason to become unstable. I would do my own research first. The function that the SIGQUIT handler calls in the end seems to be the one you mention anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, ideally from c#, but trying now from gdb. I can get full output of threads, but I have to keep constantly flushing stdout for several seconds. ```(gdb) call fflush(0)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[DllImport("__Internal")]` instead of libmono. Calling this method works, but still has problem with flushing stdout.

Easier way is to send SIGQUIT signal, it will write Full thread dump to stdout.