# Dump stack trace from stalled Xamarin.Mac application

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono, xamarin.mac

I have a Xamarin.Mac application that, from time to time, gets stalled. The log is not really useful as it hangs at different points in its lifecycle, and the scenario is hard to reproduce.

On Windows, we have the Stack Dump functionality built in into the system - from Process Explorer, find the process, and go thread by thread examining their call stacks.

Is there a tool like that for Xamarin.Mac applications, so the next time the application hangs, I can get the call stack of its threads, to try to determine the root issue?

Thanks!

Comment: With macOs you can use Activity Monitor to perform a  `Sample Process` or a `Spindump`... also quite a few cmd-line tools available... As for Mono, you can dump stack traces of all threads to stdout:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068471/4984832 or use GDB to a managed stack, etc.... Google/Bing is your friend here, there are tons of resources available from the macOS side of things and the Mono side of things.

Comment: Sample Process and Spindump show native traces from the runtime, which are not really useful as I need to see managed code traces. The SO thread you link doesn't work either, the process doesn't print anything through stderr when the application is stalled (although it does when it is not!)